# An error has occurred during web site deployment - Bot framework

Tags: botframework

I try to set up a bot since yesterday.

I uploaded my knowledge base, everything was allright and the bot started answering questions (tested in webchat).

Yesterday, I made a few changes in the code with the App Service Editor in the QnABots.cs file (changing the welcoming message).

After running the build.cmd, everything was still fine. 
I then made other changes in the QnAMakerBasDialog.cs file, with changing the wordings for DefaultNoAnswer or DefaultCardNoMatchText for example. I dit not move any single line of code other than wording.

When running the build.cmd again, got this message :

```
\> \build.cmd
        1 file(s) copied.
Installing Kudu Sync
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
```

As the build cannot be made, I even reverted the file to the original (which was still in the Release folder), and yet, the bot is still not working (tested in the webchat + the build not running).

In the Channel section of the Azure panel, got this message :

`There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code ServiceUnavailable`

I cannot understand if I did something wrong. 
Any ideas ?

Many thanks, have a good day,

Answer (score 4):

So, I fixed it. 
Apparently, running the build.cmd directly in the App Service Editor does not work and destroy the build previously made.

You'll have to use the Kudu Console, and from there you can run the build, which is now working fine.

```
D:\home>cd site
D:\home\site>cd wwwroot
D:\home\site\wwwroot>build.cmd
```

Bot is back up and running !

Comment: Hey I have the same problem, now my bot is not responding on any channels. I don't understand how to use the Kudu console, or how to get to it. Are there any tutorials?? thanks in advance

Comment: Update: I found how to get to the kudu console from this tuto https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/kudu-console-in-azure/ 
I followed your steps but my bot is still not responding :/ I'll keep looking for a solution

Comment: Same here, can you please suggest what exactly needs to be done?

Comment: @sanjanajha check out the screenshots I shared.

Answer (score 1):

From you bot service, find the Kudu Console. Then traverse the directory as previous answer describe. It was very frustrating to figure out how to rebuild the bot after I broke it building from VSCode Online editor.

[image]

[image]